# excel macro for vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I have 2 different workbooks with a set of parameters, e.g. car parts number, sales prices, etc. The 2 different workbooks will always have the same car parts numbers but they are not in order.  So I was thinking of using a `vlookup` to match the parameters on one workbook to the other related to the respective parts' numbers.

Thus, I used `vlookup` to perform this task.  It works, but I want to implement this using a macro, so I would not need to manually do the `vlookup` every time.  Is it possible to create such a macro given that the workbooks (file names) would be different every time?

I actually tried recording the macro and the `vlookup` records the parameters it needs relating to the file name.

EDIT: code from comment:

```
Sub Macro1() 
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP('[TI_DBP_effective_06 May 2013.xls]NON SLL'!C1,'[TI_DBP_effective_06 May 2013.xls]NON SLL'!C1:C3,3,FALSE)" 
    Range("I1").Select Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I1:I9779") 
    Range("I1:I9779").Select 
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, definitely possible. Please post your code that you have already (revise your question to include your macro). It should be easy to change this so that the filenames are variable, and can be selected from a standard Windows file picker dialog box.

Comment: Sub Macro1()
'
'

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP('[TI_DBP_effective_06 May 2013.xls]NON SLL'!C1,'[TI_DBP_effective_06 May 2013.xls]NON SLL'!C1:C3,3,FALSE)"
    Range("I1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("I1:I9779")
    Range("I1:I9779").Select
End Sub

Comment: thats the macro i have...the vlookup which I search with one of the parameter as TI_DBP_effective.. is only one of the files I will do such an operation on. How should i edit the macro?

Comment: hi David, the code works, thanks a lot! However, I need to tweak something to the overall coding. The criteria are still the same,however,I would like to use the car parts numbers in the first ie, the file to update to compare with file 2,which is the vlookup file.How should i edit the coding you have written?

Comment: Just a little further, is it possible to make the col the vlookup input into the file to be variable? meaning, it need not be at col i as of the program now but to where i need in that particular file, eg col j instead? Thanks alot for all the help! greatly appreciated!

Comment: see revision below. I think the changes are what you expect, look up a value from the first file, in the second file, update the first file.  the autofill formula should apply to the selected column from the input box.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. You will have to place this macro in your Personal macro workbook, so that it is available all the time, no matter what workbooks are open.  It will prompt you for two files, and then open them, and should insert the formula.  Let me know if it gives you any trouble since I am not able to test it right now.

NOTE:  This looks up the value one column to the LEFT of the cell you select, and then looks in columns 1:3 of the other file.  Modify as needed.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim file1 As String
    Dim file2 As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbLookup As Workbook
    Dim startRange As Range

    file1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select the file to update")
    If Len(Dir(file1)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    file2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select the LOOKUP file")
    If Len(Dir(file2)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set wbLookup = Workbooks.Open(file2)
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(file1)

    On Error Resume Next
    Set startRange = Application.InputBox("Select the first cell for the formula", "Autofill VLOOKUP", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not startRange Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto startRange
        startRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP('[" & wbSource.Name & "]NON SLL'!RC[-1],'[" & wbLookup.Name & "]NON SLL'!C1:C3,3,FALSE)"
        startRange.AutoFill Destination:=startRange.End(xlDown)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Probably your R1C1 notation is all wrong. See revision above but that will still cause an error with the `AutoFill` on the next line. You will have to resolve that one for now, bearing in mind this is a collaborative site, not a place where you get free outsourcing of your work, to others.

Comment: I tried changing the autofill line(the last line) to a fix line,ie at row i.However, the error is the previous statement,when i change the first lookup parameter to the source file,it wont work, but if change to the lookup file,it will. I am sorry but i really tried what i can and study it the whole day,but i have no idea what is wrong. Thanks for the help,i am really stuck.

Comment: which file contains the 3-columns where the VLOOKUP refers to? `file1` or `file2`?

Comment: its on file 2,which is the vlookup file.

Comment: this is putting a vlookup formula in `file1`, which is using a value from that worksheet "NON SLL". It is performing the Vlookup with that value, against `file2` in a worksheet of the same name ("NON SLL"), in columns 1 thru 3.  I replace this with "Sheet1" and "Sheet2" and open any two workbooks, and that line does not fail, so I suspect you are either doing something wrong, or your files do not actually contain the worksheets named "NON SLL".

Comment: I understand where i have gone wrong now.my worksheet names would be different.As such I declare the worksheets but I have a problem integrating it into the vlookup formula. I edited the coding above

Comment: @BenjaminAlonsoTan your edits have been rejected (they are attempts to comment on existing answer).  In the Vlookup formula, you will need to change it so that it doesn't refer to the worksheets. `startRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP('[" & wbSource.Name & "]NON SLL'!RC[-1],'[" & wbLookup.Name & "]NON SLL'!C1:C3,3,FALSE)`. See where it says "NON SLL" in two places? Just change those.  If you need to make this a variable, too, it's possible, but this is becoming a never-ending question and I'm not inclined to answer that in this context.